# Push-out and non-reduced schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a non-reduced scheme. Denote by $X_\mathrm{red}$ the reduced scheme associated to $X$. Assume further that $X_\mathrm{red}$ is smooth. Let $Z$ be a reduced scheme and $f:X_\mathrm{red} \to Z$ be a proper morphism. Does there exist a push-out of $X$ and $Z$ along $X_\mathrm{red}$? In other words does there exist a scheme $W$ along with morphisms from $X, Z$ to $W$ such that $$\begin{array}{lcr} X_\mathrm{red}&\to&X\\ \downarrow & \square &\downarrow\\ Z &\to &W\end{array}$$is a Cartesian diagram and $W$ satisfies the universal property of push-out?

Comment: "Assume further that $X_{red}$ is smooth": are you working a field?

Comment: @Romagny: Over the complex numbers

Comment: I still don't really have ideas (although I am rather pessimistic), but I now wonder: why do you require the diagram to be cartesian? Usually cocartesian diagrams are not cartesian, and there is no reason to require that a pushout diagram be.